# Varnish and Apache SUB DOMAIN V.Host Settings?

Tags: apache, caching, subdomain, varnish

I'm still not cleared and confusing about some specific Apache V.Host Settings against Varnish. And it is hard to find such basic thing.

I am running as a default environment setup where:

- Varnish on the `:80`
- and Apache on the `:8080`

So i put my Apache Virtual `localhost` at `:8080` like:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ..
    ServerName localhost
    ..
</VirtualHost>
```

Ok then, now please let me exactly know what about the SUB DOMAINS `<VirtualHost>` Setups?
Lets say i have 2 Virtual Sub Domains:

```
<VirtualHost *:xx>
    ..
    ServerName sub1.example.com
    ..
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:xx>
    ..
    ServerName sub2.example.com
    ..
</VirtualHost>
```

To serve them by Varnish also:

- Must their `Ports` be also `:8080` ?
- Then, what VCL settings will i need to do more?